# Need advices with a iOS crash log from apple

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, crash

Hello i just receive this crash log file from apple. Its a ios app, who is running well on iphone x, iphone 8 and 7. but apparently apple found a bug!
Is some one could help me with the crash repport.
Thank you

```
"app_name":"DropCounterFree","timestamp":"2018-03-20 06:14:50.94 -0700","app_version":"1.6.3","slice_uuid":"f23916d4-de90-36ee-9454-31d223fad7bb","adam_id":0,"build_version":"1.6.3","bundleID":"com.quentinpleyers.DropCounterGratuit","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 11.2.5 (15D60)","incident_id":"54B61F51-12C1-4C90-9614-99E891630CAA","name":"DropCounterFree"}

Incident Identifier: 54B61F51-12C1-4C90-9614-99E891630CAA
CrashReporter Key:   37f5746022c72fd95d6124bac54fb3c799b0a74d
Hardware Model:      iPad4,4
Device Model:        J85AP
Process:             DropCounterFree [5916]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2C7E36E0-0265-45C1-8398-33AAF8EEDF29/DropCounterFree.app/DropCounterFree
Identifier:          com.quentinpleyers.DropCounterGratuit
Version:             1.6.3 (1.6.3)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd.development [1]
Coalition:           com.quentinpleyers.DropCounterGratuit [1250]


Date/Time:           2018-03-20 06:14:50.4788 -0700
Launch Time:         2018-03-20 06:14:11.5318 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.2.5 (15D60)
Baseband Version:    n/a
UDID:                a8ea5a7f6d075f1783df42a0f57e7ec6f0a6516b
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0
2018-03-20 06:14:50.3874 -0700  0xec33 1024 0x0 100 hangtracerd: Client disconnected: 5916
Thread 0 name:  tid_303  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018295c2e8 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182a712f8 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 396 (pthread.c:1484)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001828cb060 __abort + 152 (abort.c:128)
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001828cafc8 abort + 152 (abort.c:99)
4   DropCounterFree                 0x0000000100924834 xamarin_printf + 4671540 (runtime.m:2335)
5   DropCounterFree                 0x0000000100865558 mono_invoke_unhandled_exception_hook + 3888472 (exception.c:1119)
6   DropCounterFree                 0x000000010082a534 mono_handle_exception_internal + 3646772 (mini-exceptions.c:2002)
7   DropCounterFree                 0x00000001008292cc mono_handle_exception + 3642060 (mini-exceptions.c:2288)
8   DropCounterFree                 0x0000000100821c8c mono_arm_throw_exception + 3611788 (exceptions-arm64.c:411)
9   DropCounterFree                 0x0000000100602cb8 throw_exception + 168
10  DropCounterFree                 0x00000001004f10c8 System_Number_StringToNumber_string_System_Globalization_NumberStyles_System_Number_NumberBuffer__System_Globalization_NumberFormatInfo_bool + 504
11  DropCounterFree                 0x00000001004efe74 System_Number_ParseInt32_string_System_Globalization_NumberStyles_System_Globalization_NumberFormatInfo + 196
12  DropCounterFree                 0x00000001004edc48 int_Parse_string_System_IFormatProvider + 40
13  DropCounterFree                 0x00000001004dcb8c System_Convert_ToInt32_string + 44
14  DropCounterFree                 0x00000001004bf258 DropCounterFree_ViewController__Timer_Elapsedb__10_0 + 62040 (/<unknown>:1)
15  DropCounterFree                 0x000000010065b274 Foundation_NSActionDispatcher_Apply + 1749620 (NSAction.cs:57)
16  DropCounterFree                 0x00000001005e6498 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 248
17  DropCounterFree                 0x0000000100838d08 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 3706120 (mini-runtime.c:2777)
18  DropCounterFree                 0x000000010089bd90 do_runtime_invoke + 4111760 (object.c:2849)
19  DropCounterFree                 0x000000010089bcec mono_runtime_invoke + 4111596 (object.c:3002)
20  DropCounterFree                 0x00000001004b46e4 native_to_managed_trampoline_3(objc_object*, objc_selector*, _MonoMethod**, unsigned int) + 18148 (registrar.m:106)
21  DropCounterFree                 0x00000001004b4890 -[__MonoMac_NSActionDispatcher xamarinApplySelector] + 18576 (registrar.m:1261)
22  Foundation                      0x00000001838432e4 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 340 (NSThread.m:1265)
23  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182def77c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24 (CFRunLoop.c:1982)
24  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182def6fc __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 88 (CFRunLoop.c:2017)
25  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182deef84 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 204 (CFRunLoop.c:2053)
26  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182decb5c __CFRunLoopRun + 1048 (CFRunLoop.c:2920)
27  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182d0cc58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 (CFRunLoop.c:3245)
28  GraphicsServices                0x0000000184bb8f84 GSEventRunModal + 100 (GSEvent.c:2245)
29  UIKit                           0x000000018c4655c4 UIApplicationMain + 236 (UIApplication.m:3956)
30  DropCounterFree                 0x0000000100684590 wrapper_managed_to_native_UIKit_UIApplication_UIApplicationMain_int_string___intptr_intptr + 1918352 (/<unknown>:1)
31  DropCounterFree                 0x00000001006363fc UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___intptr_intptr + 1598460 (UIApplication.cs:79)
32  DropCounterFree                 0x00000001006363bc UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___string_string + 1598396 (UIApplication.cs:63)
33  DropCounterFree                 0x00000001004bc894 DropCounterFree_Application_Main_string__ + 51348 (/<unknown>:1)
34  DropCounterFree                 0x00000001005e6498 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 248
35  DropCounterFree                 0x0000000100838d08 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 3706120 (mini-runtime.c:2777)
36  DropCounterFree                 0x000000010089bd90 do_runtime_invoke + 4111760 (object.c:2849)
37  DropCounterFree                 0x000000010089ea60 do_exec_main_checked + 4123232 (object.c:4726)
38  DropCounterFree                 0x0000000100821494 mono_jit_exec + 3609748 (driver.g.c:1040)
39  DropCounterFree                 0x000000010092a62c xamarin_main + 4695596 (monotouch-main.m:0)
40  DropCounterFree                 0x00000001004bc7ec main + 51180 (main.m:43)
41  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018282c56c start + 4
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the area to focus on (read the sequence of events from bottom to top):

```
9   DropCounterFree 0x0000000100602cb8 throw_exception + 168
10  DropCounterFree 0x00000001004f10c8 System_Number_StringToNumber_string_System_Globalization_NumberStyles_System_Number_NumberBuffer__System_Globalization_NumberFormatInfo_bool + 504
11  DropCounterFree 0x00000001004efe74 System_Number_ParseInt32_string_System_Globalization_NumberStyles_System_Globalization_NumberFormatInfo + 196
12  DropCounterFree 0x00000001004edc48 int_Parse_string_System_IFormatProvider + 40
13  DropCounterFree 0x00000001004dcb8c System_Convert_ToInt32_string + 44
14  DropCounterFree 0x00000001004bf258 DropCounterFree_ViewController__Timer_Elapsedb__10_0 + 62040 (/<unknown>:1)
```

Looks like a timer elapsed and attempted to parse a string to an int. The string must have contained some non numeric characters would be my guess. Try validating the string before parsing, or wrap the code in a `try-catch`.